# Window opened from sandbox iframe with allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox can't close subsequently opened child windows

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I currently have a window that was opened in a sandboxed iframe with the following attributes: `allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts` (note: allow-popups and allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox are both stated)

I am able to open a new window from a link within this iframe (let's call this Window A). Window A is able to execute javascript as expected, and able to open a new child window (via `window.open`) - let's call this child Window B.

Unfortunately, when Window A tries to close Window B by calling `close()` from the handle generated by the window.open, I receive the following error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL
>   '[Window B]'
>   from frame with URL
>   '[Window A]'. The frame
>   attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from
>   navigating its ancestors.

Does this mean that despite Window A being opened from an iframe with `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox` set, it is still sandboxed in some way? How would I be able to close Window B? Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?